# Wiremock Request Pattern Matching with Request Parameters

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spock, wiremock

I am using spock and wiremock for functional testing in a Spring Boot 2.1.5 application. The incoming url is:

```
/mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Products?$format=json
```

yes, its a pretty weird url, but I can't do anything about that.

I have set up a path matcher in JSON with:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Products.*",
    "queryParams" : {
      "$format": "json"
    },
    "headers": {
      "x-csrf-token": "",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "/../responses/mockedserver/get-products/1010873195-success-200.json"
  }
}
```

As you might be able to see, I modelled the strange looking request parameter in the "queryParams" block. This didn't work, so I then put the regex, `.*`, on the end of the url.

Both gave me the result:

```sh
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Produ                 | /mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Produ<<<<< URL does not match
cts                                                        | cts?$format=json
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, it matches, except the param part at the end, basically, I don't care about the param, so I was hoping to just wildcard it out.

One possibility is that the `$` sign is making a mess of things, should I be escaping it instead? if so, how?

The other is that its the question mark, `?`. I have tried escapting that with `\?` and `\\?`, both of which were unsuccessful.

Just concerning the part of the request block that looks important here:

```
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Products.*",
    "queryParams" : {
      "$format": "json"
    },
```

I have [seen it said elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998429/url-path-pattern-matching-in-wiremocks-pattern-matching?rq=1) that if you use `urlPath` in place of `url` that WireMock treats extra headers or query parameters without match parameters as "don't care, match anyway". But this doesn't seem to be the case here as the error output shows.

**FURTHER DISCUSSION**
I have since tried various combinations putting `urlPath`, `urlPattern` and even `urlPathPattern` as suggested, in place of `url`. All of these result in:

```sh
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
                                                           | /mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Produ<<<<< URL does not match. URLs must start with a /
                                                           | cts?$format=json
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have also tried this with and without the `queryParams` block, just in case this contributed to the matching, but it does not seem to have any effect.
I am beginning to wonder if there is some other flag i need to set in the `stubFor` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: Basically, you need urlPath, no queryParams, and a string-based regex pattern, which I solved with:

```java
/^\\/mockedserver\\/v1\\/Items\('[0-9]{10}'\)\\/Products/
```

Basically, it came down to the right combination of things.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to try "urlPathPattern" or "urlPath" instead of "url" in your mapping as the following:

```
"urlPathPattern": "/mockedserver/v1/Items('1010873195')/Products.*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I have tried `urlPath`, `urlPattern` and, although I couldn't documentation on it, `urlPathPattern` in the place of `url`. All of which resulted in there being no matched stub at all. In other words, `closest match: /`

Comment: I have just updated the question with further findings, including your suggestion @AntonHinisty